# view images in img tag is wrong

Tags: php, html

> my images view orientation wrong after view in img tag , `<img src="http://www.ilockitout.net/assets/procedure_logo/12848C457-0482-495A-8756-038C9B7980501.JPG">` is orientation view 90 degree in page if i try this src url in browser  http://www.ilockitout.net/assets/procedure_logo/12848C457-0482-495A-8756-038C9B7980501.JPG is view correct how can i solve it, in my folder this images view correct but when i img tag in scr pass than view wrong

Comment: check ur link. Its not valid

Comment: wrong path, your directory http://www.ilockitout.net/assets/procedure_logo/ didn't contain this image

Comment: ask question proper. check here [ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: now check a link

Answer (score 0):

add this css style code and add ID attribute to image

```
<style>
    #img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
</style>

<img id="img" src="http://www.ilockitout.net/assets/procedure_logo/12848C457-0482-495A-8756-038C9B7980501.JPG">
```